# How to simulate windows service crush

Tags: windows, service

I have very basic question, How to simulate windows service crush,

I found a way how to set the rules of a service to restart himself in case of failure,

Now I just want to check it,

I don't want to add code to my projects (I have 3) to simulate the crush, I prefer to simulate it from external,

I prefer so generic solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Possibilities:

- manually locate the `.exe` of the service in Task Manager and terminate it
- programmatically locate the service process and use the WINAPI [`TerminateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)